# Как проверить есть ли случайная последовательность определенных элементов в другом списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список их 3х чисел `num = [a,b,c]` и есть большой список из чисел `numbers = [[q,w,e], [f,g,h], [b,a,c]]`, программа должна выдать `True`, т.к. в `numbers` есть одна из возможных перестановок `nums`. Как это написать в программе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# подготовка, делается один раз
patterns = set(tuple(sorted(v)) for v in [[q, w, e], [f, g, h], [b, a, c]])

# проверка, делается многократно
if tuple(sorted([a, b, c])) in patterns:
    ...
```

Если числа в списках не повторяются, то можно так:

```
# подготовка, делается один раз
patterns = set(map(frozenset, [[q, w, e], [f, g, h], [b, a, c]]))

# проверка, делается многократно
if frozenset([a, b, c]) in patterns:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
num = [1, 2, 3]

test_numbers = [[1, 4, 56], [7, 76, 45], [2, 3, 1]]

def func(numbers, num):
    for i in numbers:  # Перебираем каждый вложенный список

        if sum(i) == sum(num): # Если сумма цифр вложенного списка равна 
            return True  #   сумме цифр нашего списка num возвращаем True

    return False   # Если таких совпадений нет, то возвращаем False

print(func(test_numbers, num))  # Проверяем => True
```

Comment: Список может быть из ```[[2,2,2], [1,2,3], [4,1,2]]``` а проверить нужно ```[2,1,3]``` сумма 6 есть у ```[1,2,3]``` и ```[2,2,2]```

Comment: Ах, точно!) Но уже дали верный ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations

def check_permutation(num, numbers):
    perms = set(permutations(num))
    for sublist in numbers:
        if tuple(sublist) in perms:
            return True
    return False

num = [1, 2, 3]
numbers = [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [2, 1, 3]]

result = check_permutation(num, numbers)
print(result)
```

1. Сначала прогоняем все возможные перестановки чисел из списка `num` с помощью функции `permutations`.
2. Затем проверяем, есть ли какая-либо из этих перестановок в списке `numbers`, используя цикл `for` и проверку на наличие во множестве `perms`.
3. Если находится соответствие, функция возвращает `True`, в противном случае - `False`.